# Specific type of URI Security Token in .NET

Tags: .net, security

I'm looking at a third-party app in .NET and trying to figure out what method they've used to do a URI security token.

The page URLs look something like this:

```
example.com/app/I(4b16emg)/Account/
```

The token here has obvious security uses (prevents XSRF and other types of session fixation and token theft attacks).  I'm not a hard-core .net dev.  Perhaps this is a built-in feature, as I'm pretty sure I've seen it before, but I've hard a hard time googling for it as I am not sure what to call it.

> "Security token URI" and queries like that don't seem to turn up much.

**Update with more information:**

It appears to be some sort of session token that is used in addition to the session_id cookie to authenticate sessions. It seems to cycle for all new sessions and having the wrong one immediately expires your session and resets the session cookies as well. It's not related to the username or user_id value.

In this way, it makes it difficult to execute vulnerability scans, replay attacks, session token theft, XSRF, reflected XSS and other similar attacks that rely on using stable URLs to provide injection points.

This is probably the 2nd or 3rd time I've seen the same format (a short token inside parens) in the middle of a URL in a .NET application, so I was hoping someone might identify it as part of the framework, or a readily available library.

*Just a bit of background: I do a lot of application security work, but .NET isn't my specialty.*

Answer (score 0):

That url looks like what happens when the app has cookieless sessions turned on.    This is less of a security feature, and more of a way to deal with browsers that don't support/allow cookies.

In the web.config, see if it has `<sessionState cookieless="true" />`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Comment: Thanks, David.  This site also has an _ASP.NET_SessionId_ cookie, as well as an _ASP.NET_SessionID_4b16emg_ cookie (matching the URI code).  If any of these tokens doesn't match the expected value, the whole session resets and re-assigns three new tokens.  However, I'm investigating the session flow from a black-box perspective and will not have access to the code.